# VB.NET - WNetAddConnection2 - "The network path was not found."

Tags: vb.net, unc

I am using the following code to make a connection with a network path to get the list of files.

The network path is defiantly correct, and it is possible for me to map a drive manually with the same credentials. Just when running this code, the error: "53" is displayed which means "The network path was not found.".

The error happens suddenly which suggests to me that even the connection is not being made.

```
Dim nr As New NETRESOURCE
    nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK
    nr.lpRemoteName = "\\fileserver.ourserver.com\"
    MessageBox.Show(WNetAddConnection2(nr, "Password", "ourserver.com\User", 0))
```

The other code is:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System
Imports System.IO


Public Class Form1


    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure NETRESOURCE
        Public dwScope As UInteger
        Public dwType As UInteger
        Public dwDisplayType As UInteger
        Public dwUsage As UInteger
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> _
        Public lpLocalName As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> _
        Public lpRemoteName As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> _
        Public lpComment As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> _
        Public lpProvider As String
    End Structure

    Private Const NO_ERROR As Long = 0
    Private Const RESOURCETYPE_DISK As UInteger = 1

    <DllImport("mpr.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function WNetAddConnection2(ByRef lpNetResource As NETRESOURCE, <[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByVal lpPassword As String, <[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByVal lpUserName As String, ByVal dwFlags As UInteger) As UInteger
    End Function

    <DllImport("mpr.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function WNetCancelConnection2(<[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByVal lpName As String, ByVal dwFlags As UInteger, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal fForce As Boolean) As UInteger
    End Function



End Class
```

Comment: The StructLayout attribute requires CharSet:=CharSet.Auto to make it match the function declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure why, but adding /IPC$ to the server path now lets me use it again.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using an interop class to list your files, you could use the .net Framework to [DiriectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to do the same.

Comment: Old code, was using different methods before but now using DirectoryInfo.